# Responsive Design Breaking point Messed up

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a form that is collecting a user's personal information. I've started to add control to the form using bootstrap grid. I am having issue when I reach certain breaking point. For example, 768 and 781px, one of the control will be out of place. Then, it will fall back into place at 782px and work fine. I have 3 separate css files, but they don't have anything at the moment. How do I handle it when the control as is the case between 768 and 781px?

**html file**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="FirstName" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 label-control">First Name:</label>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName"  class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <label for="middleName" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 label-control">Middle Name:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="middleName"  id="middleName" />
         </div>
         <label for="lastName" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 label-control">Last Name:</label>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName"  id="lastName" />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"></div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="FirstName" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 label-control">Sex:</label>
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
              <select id="Sex" name="Sex" class="form-control">
                  <option>Select Sex</option>
               </select>
             </div>
             <label for="middleName" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 label-control">DOB:</label>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DOB"  id="DOB" />
               </div>
               <label for="lastName" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 label-control">Race:</label>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                 <select id="Race" name="Race" class="form-control">
                    <option>Select Race</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
       </div>


@media only screen and (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px){
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width:1024px) {
}
```

**When the screen is less than 768px**
[image: When the screen is less than 768px]

**The screen is between 768 and 781 px; the lastName field is out  of place**

[image]

**Screen is 782px or more**

[image]

Comment: This is because you are using too many classes such as col-xs-12, you should ony try to use one or too and then if things mess up use a @media screen in css to make any adjustments

Comment: I am a little confused. Why is using so many columns a problem? Based upon what I've read so far, I thought the point of the col-xx-xx is to handle different screen size and re-position of controls when you reached certain break point. If the application could be used in an iPhone, Table, medium size laptop, and/or a large desktop screens, why shouldn't I used these 4 column options? I am fairly new to this, so I am hoping my questions make sense to you.

Comment: Yeah you have read right but, Having a col-md-4 for example to always resize down to mobile, try and use col-xx-xx if you want to re-do the layout for a certain screen size, I tend to always use col-md-xx and and you will find that it will do the trick most of the time

Comment: when Im home Ill help you fix this don'worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right So your question was wired, Ive tided up your code abit (not fully otherwise you wont learn) The form is now responsive from big screens down to phones.

You will see that I have only used col-md-xx to achieve the look you want. If you want something changes just pop a comment and ill be glad to do it for you

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="FirstName" class="col-md-2 label-control">First Name:</label>
       <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName"  class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <label for="middleName" class="col-md-2 label-control">Middle Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="middleName"  id="middleName" />
         </div>
         <label for="lastName" class="col-md-2 label-control">Last Name:</label>
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName"  id="lastName" />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12"></div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="middleName" class="col-md-2 label-control">DOB:</label>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DOB"  id="DOB" />
               </div>
            <label for="FirstName" class="col-md-2 label-control">Sex:</label>
             <div class="col-md-4">
              <select id="Sex" name="Sex" class="form-control">
                  <option>Select Sex</option>
               </select>
             </div>
               <label for="lastName" class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 label-control">Race:</label>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                 <select id="Race" name="Race" class="form-control">
                    <option>Select Race</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```